# How can I hide a div if the user is not signed in?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to help a friend with a website he is working on.

There is an "I agree to the terms of service" checkbox that displays a div if selected, however, I want the checkbox to only appear if the user is signed in.

How would you suggest I do this?

Comment: This has to do with the sessions. If the user session has been created show the control else not.

Comment: Just use sessions....

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please isolate the problem, post your code in the question, explain what didn't work and how did you attempt to solve it.

Comment: And also provide some code if you want to be helped more.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't seem like it uses any sessions, the login is through another website, it's not internal.

Please <a href="?login&page=checkout&game=gmod&server=ttt&pid=1"><img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_small.png" /></a> so we could process your order.

Comment: Please note that you are possibly open to SQL Injections. I may be wrong as I didn't did any more testing then replacing one url parameter with ' but I just want that you can check this.

Comment: Did any of the answers work?  If so, then you need to accept one

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, because that is a HTML page, and to check for `sessions` you need to use PHP (serverside).

[EDIT] I found something on the **Steam Web API** that might help you:

*Note that because this WebAPI does not use authentication, there are only two possible values returned: 1 - the profile is not visible to you (Private, Friends Only, etc), 3 - the profile is "Public", and the data is visible. Mike Blaszczak's post on Steam forums says, "The community visibility state this API returns is different than the privacy state. It's the effective visibility state from the account making the request to the account being viewed given the requesting account's relationship to the viewed account."*

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] variable that indicates whether the user is logged in or not.
Then in your layout you can write:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])):
?>
    <input type="checkbox" />
<?php
endif;
?>
```

So the checkbox will appear only if the user is authorized. Of course you have to perform proper session handling matching your needs

Answer (score 0):

Is this all?

```
document.getElementById('divID').style.visibility='hidden'
```

Comment: I think this is not appropriate answer to this because it does not see if the person is logged in.

Comment: No, the checkbox would have to be removed on page creation. If you don't, you could easily show it again

Answer (score 0):

Just provide an IF Statement to test if the user is logged in or not.
Lets say we have a variable of $username for the username, this will not be blank if logged it also...

Therefore use != (if not)

```
$username = 'matt';
if($username != '')
{
style="visibility: hidden"    
}
```

and put this code between your div tag.
Alternatively you chould do it using CSS and amend the CSS If they are/aren't logged in.
Finally you could just use an IF statement to totally NOT put the content in...

Either way.. [PHP IF](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) - is what you are looking for... You will need to also grab you user 'logged in' status from somewhere else.

If you are using PHP session you can test for them using some code you can find here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'])) {
      echo ''
  }
?>
```

Check whethere your primary key is set or not in the php session, in my case being SESS_MEMBER_ID